# This code works for 1-argument functions, how can I make it work for multiple-argument functions?

Tags: matrix, replacement, pattern-matching

```
Unprotect[Power];
Power[0, 0] = 1;
Protect[Power];
Unprotect[Dot];
Dot[x_, y_?NumberQ] := x y;
Dot[x_?NumberQ, y_] := x y;
Protect[Dot];
$Post = ReleaseHold[
    Hold[#] /. f_[{x__}] :> MatrixFunction[f, {x}]] &;
$PrePrint = MatrixForm;
```

This code replaces ordinary functions with MatrixFunction.

It works, for instance, with `Sqrt`:

`Sqrt[{{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}]`

This returns the matrix square root. (UPDATE: unfortunately, no)

But for `Power` it still results in element-wise function application:

`{{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}^2`

How can I make it to work with multi-argument functions as well?

Comment: Power is Listable. You'll probably need to change its attributes. That's a guess. I'm not actually sure what to expect from MatrixFunction in this regard.

Comment: @lericr what does it mean and how to change it? Is not `Sqrt` also listable?

Comment: Yes, Sqrt is also Listable, so I don't know what to tell you. But if you want to play with it `Attributes` lets you see a symbol's attributes, e.g. `Attributes[Power]`. You can set attributes with `SetAttributes`.

Comment: @lericr the difficulty is that I only replace 1-argument functions and I do not know what pattern to write for multiple-argument functions. Thhis does not work: `/. f_[{x__}] :> MatrixFunction[f, {x}] /. 
  f_[{x__}, y_] :> MatrixFunction[f[#, y] &, {x}] /. 
 f_[y_, {x__}] :> MatrixFunction[f[y, #] &, {x}]`

Comment: oh, duh. sorry. I was assuming that your code was doing the replacements that you want but it just wasn't working for Power. But you actually aren't matching 2-argument functions at all. Got it.

Comment: You may have noticed that, before going into `$Post`, code like `{{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}^2` already evaluates. Using a special head like `Matrix` to stop calculation as in your later posts is a possible work-around.

Comment: @xzczd using `Matrix` head is very useful, indeed, because it allows to separate lists and other arrays from matrices. I wish Wolfram team to include `Matrix` objects that would dot-multiply in expressions when commute, and use `MatrixFunction` when becoming arguments of any functions. This allows to straightforward use all matrix algebras in normal expressions (effectively enabling  quaternions, split-quaternions, tessarines, dual numbers, their generalizations etc).